# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (LogisticRegression with Array based feature)

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Thanks in advance for any guidance.  I'm attempting to do classification via Logistic Regression using scikit-learn where the X is Intercept and one field that is an array of heartrate data called heartrate.  Based on researching others who've also faced this error I've made sure the heartrate arrays are all the same shape/size.

It's getting the value error in sklearn/utils/validation.py line 382, in check_array on the line where a copy of the dataframe is done via array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy).  I suspect that my arrays aren't contiguous in memory and that's what's posing the problem but not sure...

Here are some code snip-its to help sleuth out the problem:

```
    def get_training_set(self):
        training_set = []
        after_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(weeks=8)
        before_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=12)
        activities = self.strava_client.get_activities(after=after_date, before=before_date)
        for act in activities:
            if act.has_heartrate:
                streams = self.strava_client.get_activity_streams(activity_id=act.id, types=['heartrate'])
                heartrate = np.array(list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, streams['heartrate'].data)))
                fixed_heartrate = np.pad(heartrate, (0, 15000 - len(heartrate)), 'constant')
                item = {'activity_type': self.classes.index(act.type),'heartrate': fixed_heartrate}
                training_set.append(item)
        return pd.DataFrame(training_set)

    def train(self):
        df = self.get_training_set()
        df['Intercept'] = np.ones((len(df),))
        y = df[['activity_type']]
        X = df[['Intercept', 'heartrate']]
        y = np.ravel(y)
        #
        model = LogisticRegression()
        self.debug('y={}'.format(y))
        model = model.fit(X,y)
```

The exception occurs in fit...

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Respect,

Mike

copied from comment for improved formatting:

```
/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1173, in 
    fit order="C") 
File "/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in 
    check_X_y ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator) 
File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in 
    check_array array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy) 
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

and the other comment:

X and y look like this:

```
X.shape=(29, 2) 
y.shape=(29,) 
X=[[1 array([74, 74, 77, ..., 0, 0, 0])] 
   [1 array([66, 67, 69, ..., 0, 0, 0])] 
   ...          
   [1 array([92, 92, 91, ..., 0, 0, 0])] 
   [1 array([79, 79, 79, ..., 0, 0, 0])]] 
y=[ 0 11 11 0 1 0 11 0 11 1 0 11 0 0 11 0 0 0 0 0 11 0 11 0 0 0 11 0 0]
```

Comment: The problem is that in `fit` you do ....?????  Edit your question so it gives real and clear information about the error and its location.  And if the error isn't obvious from that, we will need enough information to recreate the problem ourselves.

Comment: The error is occurring in the fit function of the model.  Stack as follows:
"/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py", line 1173, in fit
    order="C")
  File "/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: So `X` is a (29,2) array of dtype=object, and one of the elements (2nd column) is itself an an array.   Without getting into details, I can see why it would complain a 'setting with a sequence` - the sequence being the array.  Is the whole array supposed to be a 'feature', or each element of the array a separate feature?

Comment: @hpauji, my intent was to use a single feature to represent all of the heart-rate data.  So yes, that feature was an array of ints.  Another stackoverflow SME suggested that scikit-learn can't handle array based features so I moved the heartrate data to individual features heartrate_{1-15K} features. Algorithm works great now but it less than optimal IMHO as I'd like to easily do things like PCA, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do things work better if you change train() so look like this?

```
def train(self):
    df = self.get_training_set()
    df['Intercept'] = 1                       # (a)
    y = df['activity_type'].values            # (b)
    X = [np.concatenate(( np.array([col1]), col2 )) for col1, col2 in df[['Intercept', 'heartrate']].values.T]
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(X,y)                            # (c)
```

(a) A sequence of the correct length will be generated
(b) Use values to return an numpy array instead of another dataframe
(c) fit is done inplace

Comment: Appreciate the help.  Getting the same error in the fit function.  ValueError in check_array.  X and y look like this:

X.shape=(29, 2)
y.shape=(29,)
X=[[1 array([74, 74, 77, ...,  0,  0,  0])]
 [1 array([66, 67, 69, ...,  0,  0,  0])]
...
 [1 array([92, 92, 91, ...,  0,  0,  0])]
 [1 array([79, 79, 79, ...,  0,  0,  0])]]
y=[ 0 11 11  0  1  0 11  0 11  1  0 11  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0 11  0 11  0  0
  0 11  0  0]

Comment: Is a single feature able to be a vector array or does the whole row need to be one array?  First time I've used an array for a feature...:)

Comment: This is a problem - scikit learn can't handle a feature that is an array. You should include each element of the array in separate column. This should really be done at the dataframe level but I've included a makeshift solution in my answer

Comment: Ah hah!  Excellent.  I'll fix in the get_training_set and see if I can get it working.  Appreciate the guidance BTW!

Comment: works like a charm now!  Had to think about how to deal with 15K columns without impacting performance but that wasn't too bad.  Thanks again for your guidance.  BTW, is scikit-learn alone in this can't handle arrays?  Seems like tensors are by definition arrays so perhaps it does this easier?

Reason I ask is ideally I could do things like PCA to see if "heartrate" or other stream type features (e.g. power) are impactful rather than the 3'rd reading in an hour being impactful...

Comment: @MichaelWood I imaging that no machine learning library would want to take a mix of arrays as features if they are different shapes - which was happening for you with one as a single value and the other as a 1D array. A neural network may take in a 2D image as input (which in practice has multiple layers for RGB), but here each "array feature" has the same shape. Really we would think of the individual pixel values as being the features

Comment: Coming back to your work, [here is a good example of implementing PCA in scikit](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_pca_in_3_steps.html#shortcut---pca-in-scikit-learn). Also I'd appreciate it if you could "check mark" my initial answer as the accepted one. Cheers

Comment: Thanks again for the help @AlexG.  I'll take a look at the example tomorrow.  I marked your answer as the solution.